# Question about Linux/Android coexistence on a device are on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I just find a closed question that asks about [*"Security Issues using Android/Debian Systems at the same time on a single device"*](https://superuser.com/questions/1093111/use-maruos-or-wait-for-ubuntu-phone-with-unity-8).
[Originally](https://superuser.com/posts/1093111/revisions) was titled *"Use MaruOS or wait for Ubuntu Phone with Unity 8"*.
I slightly reformulated it to make more compliant with our rules.

The OP basically is asking for known issue using android for the phone functionalities and Debian for the desktop ones, at the same time on the same device. So two operative systems on the same device.

**I think this is a good question for Super User and I would like to read the answers about it.**

What do you think about it? I just partially edited what else should I do?

**Edit:**
I add two general considerations:

1. I see this question as the coexistence of two operative systems on a device. Moreover I see this question as a way to know how to use a mobile really as a desktop.
2. I do not consider a phone so far (in principle) from a desktop even because an average mobile phone of nowadays is somehow more powerful of an alpha station of the 90's, and we have just seen with the GPU (born for the graphic cards) how fast a device/technology projected for a purpose can radically change its application with time...

Comment: I think it's fine personally.

Comment: I think it is a better fit for [android.se] as the hardware you are asking about is a phone rather than standard computer hardware.

Comment: I donno. Seems like a pretty drastic edit , and still is asking for an opinion

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Drastic? It seems `:-)`.  I just added _"since"_, _"I would like to know"_ ,  _"What I found is"_,  erased `<br>` and moved up 2 phrases that the OP put at the end of the post. Really I changed the title.  The question without question mark but with the interrogative form is from the OP. _"Are there security Issues using Android/Debian Systems as separate (but somehow one) System on one device"_ ? Even if I'm not (yet) signed [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/) I cannot agree that Security issues are an opinion. :D

Comment: But it comes down to 'what should I get?', the question topic is *hugely* changed, and its still a question about a phone. Well two phones.

Comment: @Burgi Android Enthusiasts if for _"Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system"_,  we are ones of the multi operative systems...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I agree that the topic in the first form could be misleading, especially if you'll not read carefully the question (that's why I changed). The OP is not asking "what should I get?", but telling us that taking that device he/she was unaware about the security issues related to have two OS (that can see each other) on the device. If I ask _Which security issue there are if I make a dual boot with Windows and Linux and allow them to see both partition (it doesn't matter how)?_ I expect someone will say me, from windows you can erase the file of Linux and viceversa:not so safe...

Comment: Revision 4 of the question is now more clearly about which option/alternative they should choose

Comment: *"which option/alternative they should choose "* - So they are seeking our opinion on what option they should choose?  How is that on topic?  I read the question, and I cannot figure out, what the author's question is.  *There is not a single question mark in the current revision of the question*

Comment: @Ramhound __I would like to know if there are/which are the security Issues using Android/Debian Systems as separate (but somehow one) System on one device.__ Does it seems to you a question? maybe an [indirect one](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/24624)? :-) I believe he/she is putting the question in a context (this or that?) to help us to focus our answer, but not asking for a decision from us... BTW I'm really interested about any possible answer about it... :)

Comment: @Hastur - **I am talking about the Superuser question, not your question, **clearly.  Your question is about the linked question **is it not**?

Comment: @Ramhound You said _"There is not a single question mark in the current revision of the question"_ (in superuser). What I posted in bold above it was copied and pasted from the SuperUser question... and it is a question without question mark as it is possible to do in English... I agree a little hidden with the current bold/not bold settings...

Comment: @Hastur, my understanding, and reading of the Android tag, is that Android devices (and also phones of any kind), are off-topic except for interfacing them with a PC. So pretty much anything you want to do on one would be off-topic, including adding another OS, even though that OS would be on-topic for a question involving a PC platform. I didn't notice anybody addressing that, other than Burgi. Am I missing something?  Your edit says you consider a phone equivalent, but SU isn''t there, yet.

Comment: @Hastur A sentence in English cannot be a question without a question mark........the quoted text has since been removed, or perhaps I am missing it, because the linked question is a mess.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have a laptop with the slot for a mobile SIM card (telephone, usable as modem or to do normal calls). A friends of mine (and even some years ago) showed me a tablet with Ubuntu installed (he compiled) instead of the default android, again with the SIM card slot. Android is derived from Linux. For what I understood about MaruOS it seems to be a Linux _modded_ with an emulation layer to allow the android apps to run, so no so far from a virtual machine that runs on a windows or linux system. I would like to listen some answer instead to search from 0... ps> sorry for late answering.

Comment: @fixer1234 Moreover, the processor of raspberry pi (ARM11...) is used in the mobile phone of apple nokia.. that means that I can use those phones as computers because they are computers. SuperUser is the _"MultiOS site"_, _"for computer enthusiasts and power users... working together to build a library of detailed answers to __every question about computer software or hardware__."_. Who is more "computer enthusiasts" than a person that want to use a mobile as a desktop? `:-)`. About the tag. There is a  hierarchy in each rule system. A tag definition cannot prevail the site definition.

Answer (score 2):

In its [current revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/1093111/7), it seems off-topic. It basically comes down to "I care about Quality X and Quality Y, should I get Thing A or Thing B?" It's still a recommendation, but apparently one of software. Though there are also the follow-up questions, which might not be specific to the two options outlined earlier; I'm honestly not sure. The answer to at least one of those ("Are two specialized systems better in terms of security and performance than one general system?") depends entirely on the systems in question.

Answer (score 1):

First version was asking if they should procure a device that is currently on the market, or wait for another device will arrive. And to ask the audience which is better for their needs because it's a shopping question.

Edits made since then deepen that that is what's being asked.

Comment: __That's not true.__ I agree that the post was not written in _fluent_ English, btw the only question in interrogative form is about security issues (the OP forgot the "?"). If you are not yet convinced you can read the comment of the OP when he/she says _"It's __DEFINITELY NOT__ about __Hardware__ (because these Systems are somehow hardware-independet) and it's not about Android either! "_.

Comment: It was comprehensible enough to understand that it was asking for advice on which device to choose based on the asker's want for security. Your edit has taken the question in another direction entirely based on your explanations here

Comment: Please just for my personal curiosity decide (1) _"Edits made since then deepen that that_ (to procure a device) _is what's being asked."_ or (2) _"Your edit has taken the question in another direction entirely based on your explanations here"_?  In my edit I take the exact phrases of the OP and change the order. I had no will to drift the question somewhere. He/She followed this schema: a) context b) finding c) Question d) narrowing the possible answers. After OP makes errors but the question was good. And on this site  we should privilege Question and Answers to the form... (%)

Comment: It's both. First edit emphasizes asking for help in choosing what they want for their own setup. Then the next edit and explanations here take interpret that question to instead be about having dual OS on a device, changing the intent